# Create list of words with similar spelling

Tags: python, data-science, words

Given a word (English or non-English), how can I construct a list of words (English or non-English) with similar spelling?

For example, given the word 'sira', some similar words are:

- sirra
- seira
- siara
- saira
- shira

I'd prefer this to be on the verbose side, meaning it should generate as many words as possible.

Preferably in Python, but code in any language is helpful.

The Australian Business Register [ABN lookup tool](http://www.abr.business.gov.au/Search/ResultsActive?SearchText=sira) (a tool that finds business registration numbers based on search keywords) does a good job of this.

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: Can you approach this problem in the opposite way?  Finding the edit distance between two strings is relatively straightforward.

Comment: @jedwards unfortunately not - I am searching a database for the similar spellings and as far as I'm aware it's not that easy to find the edit distance using DB queries.

Comment: It may not be easy, but generating all possible "misspellings" is untenable.  For a one character word, there are 78 "typos" with an edit distance of just 1.  For a two character word there are something like 750.

Comment: @jedwards I actually looked into this further and Postgres is able to get strings within a certain Levenshtein distance. I'll look into that further.

Answer (score 3):

The thing you are looking for is provided by ispell (and family) of dictionaries. There is a relatively easy interface via [`hunspell`](https://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell) library.

The actual data (dictionaries) you can download [from here](https://github.com/wooorm/dictionaries) (among other places, like OpenOffice plugin pages).

There is an interface to get a number of similar words based on the edit distance suggested in the comment. Going with the example from GitHub:

```
>>> import hunspell
>>> hobj = hunspell.HunSpell('/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic', '/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff')
>>> hobj.spell('spookie')
False
>>> hobj.suggest('spookie')
['spookier', 'spookiness', 'spook', 'cookie', 'bookie', 'Spokane', 'spoken']
```

Comment: Will this suggest words that are not in the dictionary? For example, given the word 'sira', it should suggest words that are phonetically correct, but may not necessarily be in any dictionary.

Comment: I think this is a great answer. I installed the python hunspell module and started playhing with it immediately. I doubt ABN finds words that aren't in a some kind of lookup table. Also @MichaelBates, you might should consider revising your question to include strings that are word-like but are not found in any dictionary.

Comment: @Michael Bates: did it help? If so, could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

## For searching in databases use ["LIKE"](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

The query you'd want is

```
SELECT * FROM `testTable` WHERE name LIKE "%s%i%r%a%
```

Comment: The trouble is with querying the dictionary of plain-text words in all of their forms (where do you get one? how to query?)

Comment: @sophros Oxford Dictionaries provide an API https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/